# Adding claims to a ClaimsPrincipal after user creation in with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm using OnTokenValidated to add additional claims to a ClaimsPrincipal when the user logs on. This is working fine for users that alredy exist in the database.

However, to create a new user, I email a link to the user that includes a nonce. This is handled by a controller action that requires them to authenticate. Once authenticated, the controller action checks that the nonce is valid for creation of the specified account, and that the user is authenticated with the correct email address, then adds the user in the database.

The problem is that OnTokenValidated is called before the user is created in the database, so the claims aren't added for the new user.

I believe I need to sign the user out and back in again. How do I do that without forcing them to re-authenticate?

Comment: Use a claims transformer (IClaimsTransformation) to add your additional claims. If necessary (because it's called too early), get a refresh token, and then use that to request a new access token. See https://brockallen.com/2017/08/30/beware-in-asp-net-core-2-0-claims-transformation-might-run-multiple-times/

Comment: That's really useful, thanks @ColinSmith. Do you know how, using MSAL, I force a token refresh?

Comment: I'm doing this:

AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(_b2cOptions.CurrentValue.ApiScopes.Split(' '), accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithForceRefresh(true).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

but it doesn't seem to cause OnTokenValidated to be called again